# Split single column csv file into unequal parts

Tags: python, csv

I have a big single column csv file, which i want to split into tiny chunks:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
10
```

Such that the output csv should look like:

```
1  | 3  | 6  | 8  |  
2  | 4  | 7  | 9  |  
*  | 5  | *  | 10 |
```

and

`*` indicating no number in column.

Can anyone please help me in this regard.
Thanks

Comment: How would you determine where `*` should be placed?

Comment: i added "*" so i could align with "|" to look like a table

Comment: instead of "*" you can imagine an empty space

Comment: How would you would decide which columns should have an empty place and which should get the 'extra' numbers? (same question as Tadeck)

Comment: @Navin: Could you edit your question? I have properly formatted it, so no space will be skipped. Let me rephrase my question: how would you determine where empty cells should be placed?

Comment: @Tadeck i want to split the single column csv file into multiple columns in a sequence ie first column contains 1 and 2, second column 3 4 5and third column 6 7 and so on..

Comment: @Navin:It's still completely unclear what the logic behind your desired output is.  What should the output look like if there were nine or twelve lines in the input file?

Comment: the logic is; i want to split the single column csv file into multiple columns in a sequence of 2 3 2 3 2 3 and so on..so if there were 12 lines in the input file: the output would be [1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7] [8,9,10], [11,12]. Please in case its confusing i would totally rephrase the question. apologies for being unclear

Comment: @Navin it still is unclear to me where the sequence 2,3,2,3,2,3 comes from. Do you _always_ want 2 numbers in the first column, 3 in the second, 2 in the third etc... and you'll keep expanding the total number of columns to fit the total number of entries you have?

Comment: @Navin, you're aware that the exact thing you describe is not possible for some inputs, right? What should happen to an 11-item column? Or a 13-item column?

Comment: @senderle What is not verified in the output CSV file I obtain, please ?

Comment: @eyquem, the OP asked for alternating columns of 2 and 3. Yours ends with a column of 1. The OP never explained whether that was acceptable, or whether instead the code should arrange the columns differently.

Comment: @senderle Now the OP has the choice between two codes.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly but easy solution:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

def split_2_3(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        it = (line.strip() for line in f)
        while True:
            yield next(it), next(it), "*"
            yield next(it), next(it), next(it)

with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
    output.writerows(izip(*split_2_3("input.txt")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that can hold any number of lines in the input file:

```
import csv

def split_2_3(filename,cnt = 0):
    dd = {0:[],1:[],2:[]}
    ecr = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            ecr.append('\nline %d : %r\n' % (i,line))
            if (i+cnt-2)%6:
                ecr.append('%r put in dd[%d]\n'
                           % (line.strip(),(i+cnt)%3))
                dd[(i+cnt)%3].append(line.strip())
            else:
                ecr.append("'*' put in dd[%d]"
                           % ((i+cnt)%3 ))
                dd[(i+cnt)%3].append('*')
                cnt += 1
                ecr.append('  and  %r put in dd[%d]\n'
                           % (line.strip(),(i+cnt)%3))
                dd[(i+cnt)%3].append(line.strip())
    print ''.join(ecr)
    yield dd[0]
    yield dd[1]
    yield dd[2]


with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
    output.writerows(split_2_3("input.txt"))
```

exemple with an input file having 13 lines:

```
line 0 : '1\n'
'1' put in dd[0]

line 1 : '2\n'
'2' put in dd[1]

line 2 : '3\n'
'*' put in dd[2]  and  '3' put in dd[0]

line 3 : '4\n'
'4' put in dd[1]

line 4 : '5\n'
'5' put in dd[2]

line 5 : '6\n'
'6' put in dd[0]

line 6 : '7\n'
'7' put in dd[1]

line 7 : '8\n'
'*' put in dd[2]  and  '8' put in dd[0]

line 8 : '9\n'
'9' put in dd[1]

line 9 : '10\n'
'10' put in dd[2]

line 10 : '11\n'
'11' put in dd[0]

line 11 : '12\n'
'12' put in dd[1]

line 12 : '13\n'
'*' put in dd[2]  and  '13' put in dd[0]

line 13 : '\n'
'' put in dd[1]
```

and the result in the output CSV file:

```
1|3|6|8|11|13
2|4|7|9|12|
*|5|*|10|*
```

### edit

To answer to what senderle pointed out (note that I added ljust(5) in the code to make the displaying of the content of output.csv clearer:

```
import csv

def split_2_3(filename,cnt = 0):
    dd = {0:[],1:[],2:[]}
    ecr = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f):
            ecr.append('\nline %d : %r\n' % (i,line))
            if (i+cnt-2)%6:
                ecr.append('%r put in dd[%d]\n'
                           % (line.strip(),(i+cnt)%3))
                dd[(i+cnt)%3].append(line.strip().rjust(5))
            else:
                ecr.append("'*' put in dd[%d]"
                           % ((i+cnt)%3 ))
                dd[(i+cnt)%3].append('*'.rjust(5))
                cnt += 1
                ecr.append('  and  %r put in dd[%d]\n'
                           % (line.strip(),(i+cnt)%3))
                dd[(i+cnt)%3].append(line.strip().rjust(5))

        while (i+cnt)%3!=2:
            i += 1
            dd[(i+cnt)%3].append('*'.rjust(5))

    print ''.join(ecr)
    yield dd[0]
    yield dd[1]
    yield dd[2]


with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    output = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
    output.writerows(split_2_3("input.txt"))
```

With a file input.txt containing:
'1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11'
the created ouput.csv is

```
1    |3    |6    |8    |11   
2    |4    |7    |9    |*    
*    |5    |*    |10   |*
```

With a file input.txt containing:
'1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11\r\n'
the resulting output.csv is the same

With a file input.txt containing:
'1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11\r\n\r\n'
the result is:

```
1    |3    |6    |8    |11   
2    |4    |7    |9    |     
*    |5    |*    |10   |*
```

With a file input.txt containing:
'1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n10\r\n11\r\n\r\n\r\n'
the ouput.txt becomes:

```
1    |3    |6    |8    |11   |     
2    |4    |7    |9    |     |*    
*    |5    |*    |10   |*    |*
```

Results are visually the same if there are lines with blanks in them instead of just '\r\n' but the values recorded in the output.csv file will be blanks